# Can't connect to wss:// (Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

I have VPS with LAMP. I have free signed SSL certificate from Startssl.com (ssl certificate working correctly)

With `http://` protocol I can connect to `ws://chat.example.com:1337/some-variable` but when I replace protocol `http://` to `https://` then I can't connect to `wss://chat.example.com:1337/some-variable`

When I try to connect to `wss://` I'm getting error `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Why?

```
// http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/
"use strict";

// Optional. You will see this name in eg. 'ps' or 'top' command
process.title = 'node-chat';

// Port where we'll run the websocket server
var webSocketsServerPort = 1337;

// websocket and http servers
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var $ = require("jquery");

    /**
     * HTTP server
     */
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Not important for us. We're writing WebSocket server, not HTTP server

});
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + webSocketsServerPort);
});

/**
 * WebSocket server
 */
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    // WebSocket server is tied to a HTTP server. WebSocket request is just
    // an enhanced HTTP request. For more info http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-6
    httpServer: server
});
```

**EDIT**

I have source from http://ahoj.io/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To critique my answer better, as the last one was a mistake and I didn't mean to submit it until after I finished digging, try this:

```
    // Private key and certification
    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt')
    };


    var server = https.createServer(options, function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received HTTP(S) request for ' +     request.url);
    }
```

Comment: `cert/server.key` can be saved in `etc/apache2/myssl/server.key`? Or must be in `var/www/html/` ?

Comment: Not a problem. I apologise for the first answer - never meant to submit it. Used the text field as a "notepad" if you would while I looked in to it. :)